# mdframed: setting up a global environment

Tags: mdframed, grouping

How do I set up a global `mdframed` environment?

Would I add something like this in the preamble:

```
\newtheorem{laws}
\mdfsetup{%
  background = blue!30,%
  roundcorner = 5pt
}
}
```

but then I want to be able to add the title by doing

```
\begin{mdframed}{title}
  information
\end{mdframed}
```

The new environment would then look like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you need, but you could use `\newmdtheoremenv` and the optional argument for the defined structure:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newmdtheoremenv[
  backgroundcolor = blue!30,
  roundcorner = 5pt,
]{laws}{Law}

\begin{document}

\begin{laws}[Newton's First Law]
Every body persists in its state of being at rest or of moving uniformly straight forward, except insofar as it is compelled to change its state by force impressed.
\end{laws}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If no numbering and no special treatment (as in theorem-like structure) is needed, then one could say something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newmdenv[
  backgroundcolor = blue!30,
  roundcorner = 5pt,
]{lw}
\newenvironment{laws}[1]
  {\begin{lw}[frametitle=#1]}
  {\end{lw}}

\begin{document}

\begin{laws}{Newton's First Law}
Every body persists in its state of being at rest or of moving uniformly straight forward, except insofar as it is compelled to change its state by force impressed.
\end{laws}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could the word law and the indexing be removed?

Comment: I added a picture to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: @dustin please see my updated answer.